# Public source for financial company customer counts?

Tags: data-request, finance

I've built [a dashboard](https://www.thedash.com/dashboard/Pe66xUgvCq) that uses [complaints data](http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaintdatabase/) from the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau to show the companies with the most complaints. The results are kind of interesting, but also rather predictable: the biggest companies have the most complaints (Bank of America, Capital One, et al). Obviously bigger companies are going to have more complaints than smaller companies, regardless of the quality of service.

Is there an open data source with customer counts that I can use to give these numbers balance? So I can say something like "Capital One: 12 complaints per 1000 customers" or something.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you will find the number of customer per company but you can asses their size using other more accessible metrics like their revenue or number of employee.

Comment: Good suggestion! Do you know of an open data source for those metrics?